# Android, Removing RoboGuice help needed to replace getInjector().getInstance

Tags: android, roboguice

I'm working on a third party app and I need to remove RoboGuice and I need to know what I need to do to replace various getInjector methods with android code
In an activity I have

```
private CodeView codeView;
...

this.codeView.setHelper(RoboGuice.getInjector().getInstance(Helper.class));
```

Is this just a case of setting up an instance of the Helper class and initialising it in onCreate of the activity?

I also need to know how/what I need to do to replace

```
@Inject
private Configuration config;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just like creating a new instance of any object.  In onCreate() do:

```
codeView.setHelper(new Helper());
```

Comment: Any idea what @Inject
private Configuration config; does?

Comment: I believe all it does is instantiate a new instance of that object type for you. Similar to : Configuration = new Configuration();